# Get-content file locks the file from other processes

Tags: powershell, batch-file, weblogic

I'm trying to parse weblogic logfile. I used below command in a batch file in an infinite loop

```
powershell -command "& {Get-Content "%file_name%" | Select-Object -last 1}" | findstr /m "shut  start" >> !parse_file!
```

The weblogic has no problem writing into the file but when it restarts, it moves the file as an old file and creates a new file with the same name. This process is prevented by the code I used and hence weblogic can't restart.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this while I can get my task done

Comment: I don't know if this helps your issue but what version of PowerShell do you have where the task is running? You could just use `-Tail 1` with `Get-Content` instead of reading the whole file. Also `"& {(Get-Content "%file_name%" -Tail 1)" |  findstr /m "shut  start" >> !parse_file!` should close the file handle sooner. Again I don't know if any of this matters.

Comment: That's pretty convoluted. Why run a PowerShell command and pipe to findstr.exe? Just create a PowerShell script to do what you need and run that.

Comment: Instead of invoking PowerShell, you could just `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%file_name%") do set "lastline=%%I"` and then `echo %%I | findstr /m etc`.  It'd be much faster I bet.

Comment: Matt: exactly as I thought

Comment: Bill_stewart: I can run powershell commands, but can't run scripts. Some sort of privilege I need from sys admin. I can't get it I guess

Comment: rojo: I guess what you said looks better...let me give it a try...

Comment: @Master_Roshy If you include `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` at the top of your .ps1 scripts you might have better luck running them.

Comment: You might be right. I thought it was some privilege problem and I took days to write lame batch scripts!!! I wish I can write powershell scripts, but then starting from scratch is a pain. 

If I use the set-executionpolicy remotesigned  and still use the powershell -last command won't it lock the file as I asked initially

Comment: It won't effect the in-line commands like you're using in your batch script.  It's only relevant in .ps1 or .ps1m scripts I think.

Comment: Simply copy the logfile to a temporary file and then process the copy in case it's small?

Comment: rojo: the command you gave to substitute in place of powershell didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Something strange rojo

The code doesn't accept the file for some reason. Look at this:

Comment: [code]

D:\cm\ias\utility\healthcheck\bin>for /F "usebackq delims=" %I in (D:\oracle\midtierjsp\user_projects\domains\cmicdev4jv10x\servers\cmicdev4jv10x_dev4v10_cmic_ca\logs\cmicdev4jv10x_dev4v10_cmic_ca.out)
The system cannot find the file D:\oracle\midtierjsp\user_projects\domains\cmicdev4jv10x\servers\cmicdev4jv10x_dev4v10_cmic_ca\logs\cmicdev4jv10x_dev4v10_cmic_ca.out.

D:\cm\ias\utility\healthcheck\bin>more D:\oracle\midtierjsp\user_projects\domains\cmicdev4jv10x\servers\cmicdev4jv10x_dev4v10_cmic_ca\logs\cmicdev4jv10x_dev4v10_cmic_ca.out.
<Sep 23, 2015 7:44:48 AM> <NodeManager> 
[/code]